# How to update row in panda data from based on previous row condition met

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a final data set in a data frame in panda and would like to identify weeks that are classified as a 'Winner. Weeks are classified as 'Winners' when the total count for the week is greater than the 20% the weekly average and when the previous week is not a 'Winner'. i.e., (Weekly_counts[B] > Winner_Num [H]) and the previous row is not 'Winner'

[Excel Example] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mAex.png)

How to do this in panda?

I've tried to use the shift() and Lamda function but not getting the expected results [I].

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k). Please [read this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as to why it is discouraged.

Comment: Also try posting the code you have tried, along with any error messages or why the code does not work